# Merging 2 data frame with matched column names; each matched column next to each other

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I wish to merge two data frames that have the same length and column names in a way that I can have the values of the columns with the same name next to each other.

A simple example

```
ex1<-data.frame( c(1:5), c(2:6), c(9:13) )
ex2<-data.frame( c(12:16), c(23:27), c(100:104) )
colnames(ex1)=c("a","b","c")
colnames(ex2)=c("a","b","c")
```

This would give

```
> ex1
  a b  c
1 1 2  9
2 2 3 10
3 3 4 11
4 4 5 12
5 5 6 13

> ex2
   a  b   c
1 12 23 100
2 13 24 101
3 14 25 102
4 15 26 103
5 16 27 104
```

What I want is:

```
> comb_ex
  a  a b  b  c   c
1 1 12 2 23  9 100
2 2 13 3 24 10 101
3 3 14 4 25 11 102
4 4 15 5 26 12 103
5 5 16 6 27 13 104
```

Also, once the data frames are merged, how could I rename the columns, mantaining its original name, but adding an index so I could identify from which data frame those values came from?

```
> comb_ex
  a1 a2 b1 b2 c1  c2
1  1 12  2 23  9 100
2  2 13  3 24 10 101
3  3 14  4 25 11 102
4  4 15  5 26 12 103
5  5 16  6 27 13 104
```

Comment: Something among these lines probably `comb_ex <- cbind(ex1, ex2);
names(comb_ex) <- make.names(names(comb_ex), unique = TRUE);
comb_ex[sort(names(comb_ex))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty self-explanatory. Look at the help pages for `?cbind.data.frame`, `?make.unique`, `?'names<-'` and `?"["` for further explanation.

```
> comb <- cbind(ex1,ex2)
> names(comb) <- make.unique(names(comb))
> comb[sort(names(comb))]
  a a.1 b b.1  c c.1
1 1  12 2  23  9 100
2 2  13 3  24 10 101
3 3  14 4  25 11 102
4 4  15 5  26 12 103
5 5  16 6  27 13 104
```